# Disable the entire screen during ajax request

Tags: primefaces

So when you create  a dialog with primefaces it disables all of the page in the background. Is there a good way to do that without the dialog box?

Basically I want to disable the whole page during a specific ajax request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup its called BlockUI ,

[BlockUI](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml)

```
<p:panel id="pnl" header="My Panel">
    //content
    <p:commandButton id="saveBtn" value="Save" />
</p:panel>
<p:blockUI block="pnl" trigger="saveBtn" />
```

also , take a look at the user guide at the BlockUI section...

Comment: No, we have our own block ui implementation, not using that 3rd party plugin. Just the idea is same.

Comment: @CagatayCivici , sorry , my bad :) thought so cause of the identical name... will fix my answer

Comment: @Ebrahim yes it is (now)

Answer (score 3):

You could create a div that was the size of the HTML give it a z-index very high, after that you hide or show this div when you want to block or show the page.

Like this

```
<html>
<div class="blocker"></div>
<div class="page">
    Your content here
    <button id="btn">teste</button>
</div>
<html>
```

> ```
> .page{z-index: 900}
> .blocker{z-index:1000;height:100%;width:100%;background: gray; opacity:0.7; position: absolute;}
> ```

​Check it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/6nDtu/31/

Comment: html elements are not blocked and can still be used. e.g. text fields can be edited.